# Returning and Accessing a Multidimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, getter

Function getSalon() returns a two-dimensional boolean array.

```
bool** getSalon()
{
    return salon;
}
```

When I try to access it's values that doesn't seems to work.

```
someObject.getSalon()[i][k];
```

But if I write it in this way, I get the first element.

```
someObject.getSalon();
```

How can I access this arrays' all elements properly?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped me to save the problem. The program was closing itself. I made the declaration wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`operator[]` has higher precedence than `operator.`.Try this:

```
(someObject.getSalon())[i][k];
```